# GIT: utilizing a different branch without committing it

Tags: git, drupal

On projects or team sometimes works serially on different parts of the same deliverable. For example, someone is working on theming and presentation and and someone on a module that prepares data for theming.

What are some ways to utilize someone else's work or to "turn on" a feature branch and someone's data work, without having to commit the code with the separate personal work and theming branch?

Comment: I generally keep local branches that have my feature work rebased on another person's branch if I need to. Keeping it rebased separates your code unlike a merge, so you can keep track of your changes easily.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: "Commit often and commit early."

### Setup

Let's say that have 2 branches `feature/theming` and `feature/data_for_theming`.

### Scenario

Developer (A) working on `feature/theming` wants to use code from `feature/data_for_theming` being developed by (B).

### Workflow Option 1

`A` merges changes from `feature/data_for_theming`.

If `B` finishes `feature/data_for_theming` before `A` then `A`'s pull request to `master` will only contain `A`'s changes. Good.

If `B` finishes `feature/data_for_theming` after `A` then `A`'s pull request to `master` will contain `A`'s and `B`'s changes. Probably undesired.

### Workflow Option 2

A 3rd branch `feature/theming_with_data` is created.

When `A` or `B` want to test the code changes together they checkout `feature/theming_with_data` merge `feature/data_for_theming` and `feature/theming` and run their tests.

Comment: That doesn't seem to accomplish "previewing" someone's work, or allowing a virtual overlay of  other work without committing it.  With *option 1* there's a tricky bit of ensuring one thing is finished before another. The goal is preparing two features separately. With *option 2* you'd have to switch frequently switch branches to update code and preview integration.

Comment: Perhaps a good workflow is to add a `.gitignore` in their directory, then remove it on the integration branch?